# Inserting Data in to db while going forward in asp.net survey web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Here is my code which populates the question from db table based on their object type (droprdown,checkbox,radioutton..)

```
  if (str.Trim().ToLower() == "dropdown box")
            {
                string[] strArr = strOptions.Split('|');
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ddl";
                ddl.CssClass = "CheckBox";
                ddl.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
                // ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("test", "test"));

                if (strArr.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in strArr)
                    {

                        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(s, s));

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ddl = new DropDownList();
                    ddl.ID = "ddlContent1";
                    ddl.Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
                    plc.Controls.Add(ddl);
                }
                plc.Controls.Add(ddl);
            }
            if (str.Trim().ToLower() == "checkbox list")
            {

                string[] strArr = strOptions.Split('|');

                if (strArr.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in strArr)
                    {
                        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

                        chk.ID = s;
                        chk.Text = s;
                        chk.CssClass = "CheckBox";

                        if (strFooterOptions == "If all of the above are checked, please SUBMIT.  [Click here to Submit]")
                            chk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkAllCheckBox()");
                        plc.Controls.Add(chk);
                        plc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                    }

                }
```

and my prev and next button , when you hit next it shows you another questions in another sections.

```
 protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // int section = 1;

        section = section + 1;
        btnPrev.Enabled = true;
        FillSection();

    }
    protected void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            section = section - 1;
            FillSection();

    }
```

How can i create a method to insert responses to database when i hit next?. 
Any idea Appreciate

Thanks

Comment: you forgot to ask a question. What do you want?

Comment: ok.Thanks i just edited it .I just need one simple example source code because i dont know what to do..

Comment: How did you create method for retrieving data in `FillSection()`? It should be similar to that, instead of reading from database you should write code to get values from form and save to database, and you should call this before incrementing your section value

Comment: Yes it is FillSection() , can give me a small pice of source code..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you store your survey options I think. I made a similiar thing, storing all options in same row in database. First created a cookie to store what survey is taken (ex: all city pages have surveys and London is taken). Then I created a function to do the db stuff,

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from your_survey_table where column=cookievalue) 
INSERT INTO your_survey_table (your_columns_here) VALUES (@your_values) 
ELSE 
UPDATE your_survey_table SET option2=@your_value
```